# Not releasing MediaPlayer causes battery drain

Tags: android, service, cpu, battery

I'm working on an app that uses a MediaPlayer object to play H.264 MP4 videos from a WallpaperService as it is a live wallpaper app. Battery drain occurs while the device (Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1) is idle and sleeping if I pause/stop the MediaPlayer with mediaPlayer.pause() or mediaPlayer.stop(). The drain is about 3-7%/hour as tested multiple times overnight. As soon as I release the media player with mediaPlayer.release(), the battery drain goes back to a more normal 1%/hour. I pause/stop the mediaPlayer when onVisibilityChanged calls false. The phone is reporting to be going to sleep in both the stock Android battery chart and Better Battery Stats.

How can this battery drain be explained if the CPU is going into a sleep state successfully?

EDIT: Something new I've discovered is that when calling mediaPlayer.setSurface(null) right before mediaPlayer.pause(), the idle battery use comes back to normal. I can then do mediaPlayer.setSurface(surface) to set it back before mediaPlayer.start(). The problem is there's some black artifacting for a couple of seconds after restarting.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a precise answer but can give you what to look for. I suspect what is going on is that pause() is checking for events frequently enough to keep the processor from entering the deeper sleep/C-states. In contrast, stop() doesn't need to check for events and so allows the processor to enter a deep sleep state. I wrote [an article on sleep states](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/power-management-states-p-states-c-states-and-package-c-states) some years back.

I suspect that the writers of the function decided to check more frequently than is necessary. This is a very common mistake due to the developers thinking that shorter sleeps / more frequent checking result in better response (which it almost never does). You can check this by using a processor power monitor that actually checks the hardware sleep states. Unfortunately, most don't and only check for processor independent "equivalents".

So let's get back to your question: What can you do about it. I can give you some advice but none of it is very satisfying:

1. Check for an API or data structure that allows you to set the
   checking interval for pause(). By the way, I don't know of any.
2. Write your own. Of course, this complicates writing platform independent apps
3. Use an alternative media player that has done this correctly
4. Hammer on google until it's fixed

Like I said, none of this is very satisfying. By the way, searching the net, I found evidence that this has happened more than once with new Android releases.

Good luck and let us know what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Looking into pause() it leads to a native method that I can't check. Something new I've discovered is that if I do mediaPlayer.setSurface(null) right before mediaPlayer.pause(), the idle battery use comes back to normal. I can then do mediaPlayer.setSurface(surface) to set it back before mediaPlayer.start(). The problem is there's some black artifacting doing this for a couple of seconds after restarting.

Comment: New edit as well: the same thing occurs with mediaPlayer.stop(). If you don't do mediaPlayer.release(), battery drain continues.